# How do I hide one of my posts from the front page?

Tags: support

Accidentally discovered a new StackOverflow feature. I recently edited six of my old questions to include a tag which I felt would be relevant and make them easier to access by anyone with the same problem.

However, it appears that an edit from the author pushes the question back to the front page. So now, six of my old (solved!) questions are polluting the front page and making everyone else's (relevant!) questions less visible. Is there any way for me to take these posts off the front page, besides deleting them?

I guess this problem will resolve itself in a few hours, but it feels bad to take up so much space and attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer.. no. The front page shows recent activity.

IMO, it is great that you are maintaining your older questions. Keep it up! :)